# Subversion import existing project is much smaller than first checkout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have an existing project that I imported into subversion using TortoiseSVN. Total project size says 1.45MB. Total folder size on my machine is 9.72MB.

Create new folder, right-click, checkout 7.14MB transferred and 19.4MB on my machine.

Can anyone explain this to me? I did a quick KDiff on the folders and they're identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVN duplicates each file to have a copy of the base version.

The 19.4 MB in your checked out copy is roughly 2 times 9.72 MB of the original project - i.e. duplicate files.

The 7.14MB you checked out is compressed from the repository - that is, 9.72 MB compressed to save bandwidth.

Comment: maybe it is worth to mention that svn does this so that it can perform some operations (diff, revert...) offline...

Comment: so the extra that KDiff probably doesn't pick up by default is all the hidden files in .svn subfolders throughout the project? I always see them, just never take the time to look at their size. thanks!